# Как сделать подменю в telegram на языке python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Мне нужно сделать подменю **в телеграмме на python** [image: при нажатии на эту кнопку должна выводиться подкатегория] При нажатии на кнопку *"вывод подкатегории"* должен появиться другой текст с кнопками пример:

> ```
>     Товары:
> ```
>
> *товар 1*         *товар 2*

**(товар 1 и товар 2 это кнопки при нажатии которых вылезает цена)**

Пример кода:

````
from telegram import Update, Bot, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler, CallbackContext

from credits import bot_token

#Включает бота, настройка бота.
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)
updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

#команды; настройка команд.
#меню при вызове /info
def info(update, context):#при старте команды /info
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Вывод текста", callback_data='1'), InlineKeyboardButton("Вывод подкатегории(товаров)", callback_data='2')]]
    update.message.reply_text('Тест', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#реагирование на нажатие кнопок.
def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    #реагирование на кнопки первоначального меню(/info)
    if query.data == "1":
        context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, "вывод текста")
    elif query.data == "2":
        #вывод подменю при нажатие на "подкатегории"
        keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Товар 1", callback_data='2b_1'), InlineKeyboardButton("Товар 2", callback_data='2b_1')]]
        update.message.reply_text('Покупка товаров:', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
    #реагирование на кнопки подменю "buy gems"
    elif query.data == "2b_1":
        context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, "130 руб")
    elif query.data == "2b_2":
        context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, "350 руб")

#вид команды
info_handler = CommandHandler('info', info)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
button_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(button)

#Добавление команд в диспетчер(бот реагирует на команды)
dispatcher.add_handler(info_handler)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dispatcher.add_handler(button_handler)

#Важно не изменить. Обновление страницы получение сообщений.
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle() ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context.bot.edit_message_text` - для редактирования отправленного ранее сообщения. Возможно кому то поможет

```
def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    query.answer()
    #реагирование на кнопки первоначального меню(/info)
    if query.data == "1":
        context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, "вывод текста")
    elif query.data == "2":
        #вывод подменю при нажатие на "подкатегории"
        keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton("Товар 1", callback_data='2b_1'), InlineKeyboardButton("Товар 2", callback_data='2b_1')]]
        context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='Покупка товаров:', reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))
    #реагирование на кнопки подменю "buy gems"
    elif query.data == "2b_1":
        context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, "130 руб")
    elif query.data == "2b_2":
        context.bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, "350 руб")
```